# Angular - Two different lazy loaded modules associated to subpaths of the same path

Tags: angular, lazy-loading

I have these routes

```
/items/:id
/items
/items/:id/edit
... etc
```

I want to put the component, to which I map /items/:id/edit, inside a separate lazy loaded module than the components to which the other routes are mapped.

I want to do this because the component associated to /items/:id/edit is very heavy and calls a lot of submodules that are not necessary for the other routes.

Ideally, I would like to do something like this configuration (that unfortunately doesn't work):

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { // If the route matches "items/:id/edit", then look inside this module
        path: 'items/:id/edit',
        loadChildren: './items_editor/items_editor.module#ItemsEditorModule',
      },
      { // Otherwise look inside this other one
        path: 'items',
        loadChildren: './items/items.module#ItemsModule',
      },
    ]);
  ],
});
```

At the moment, since I didn't find a way to achieve my goal, I worked around it by renaming the path to "items/:id/edit" into "items_editor/:id":

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      {
        path: 'items',
        loadChildren: './items/items.module#ItemsModule',
      },
      {
        path: 'items-editor',
        loadChildren: './items_editor/items_editor.module#ItemsEditorModule',
      },
    ]);
  ],
});
```

However, I don't like this change because they are not REST names.

Comment: `Ideally, I would like to do something like this configuration (that unfortunately doesn't work):` Why isn't that working? routing issues? Is it loading the component because of partial URI match?

Comment: @briosheje it works as far as you don't put parameters in the portion of the url that needs to map to the lazy loaded module. With parameters, I couldn't get it working (until today).

Comment: Okay, so that's a routing issue. The answer below is fine, there are other ways to workaround that, but using UrlMatcher is indeed the cleverest solution here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the only option for this case is using UrlMatcher in route config, and with the help of it dont delegate items/:id/edit path to the ItemsModule, see https://angular.io/api/router/UrlMatcher fore details

Comment: That was exactly what I needed. I also found this github issue where it explains how to do this in detail: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/23866